# regex require next character to be a number if dot is found

Tags: javascript, regex

I would like to validate something like this, Numeric values and or with the dot

These would be valid:

- 1
- 1.1
- 12.12.12
- 123.123.123.12
- 1.12.123.12345.123456

These would not be valid:

- .1
- 1.
- 123.123.
- 123..

What I've tried

- `/^[\d*\.?\d*]+$/.test(the_number_from_form_input_field)`
- `this.value.match(/[^\d*\.?\d*$]/)`
- `/^[\d+(\.\d)?]+$`

What I'm currently using

- `/^[\d\.]+$/.test(the_number_from_form_input_field)`
- `this.value.match(/[^\d\.]/)`

Would like this to work with the .match() and .test()

Comment: what has jQuery got to do with it?

Comment: @Alnitak just listing all possible factors that could alter the outcome

Comment: I can assure you, jQuery ain't one of them...

Comment: Your third 'What I've tried' could use a + after second \d

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
myString.test(/^\d+(\.\d+)*$/);
```

[JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4qwnn/)

-edit- Thanks veeTrain, last `\d*` removed as it did not do anything. (It's still in the fiddle)

Comment: I agree that your solution works, but your last `\d*` doesn't do anything. The OP was looking for a solution to validate and zero or more digits will never reject anything.

Comment: Phill, You're welcome! And veeTrain, nice. How can I not have noticed that?

Comment: @rsplak; not a problem. Feel free to upvote my answer if you found this information useful. Pretty amazing how regex is so flexible so that both solutions work (finding digits then optional dot+digits versus an optional dot+digits followed by mandatory digits)

Answer (score 4):

This may be simpler if you reverse the test:

```
if (/\.([^\d]|$)/.test(myString)) {
    // test failed
}
```

i.e. look for a literal dot *not* followed by a digit, or by the end of the string.

Comment: This works but it also allows non numeric characters as well: http://jsfiddle.net/4qwnn/7/

Comment: @PhillPafford strictly speaking, you didn't specify that - you _only_ said that if there's a dot, it must be followed by a digit.  You said nothing about any other characters in the string.

Answer (score 2):

Don't know about jquery but I think this should work

```
^\d+(\.\d+)*$
```

Comment: fortunately for you, the question has nothing to do with jQuery, which is why I edited it out.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could find these values this way:

```
/^(\d+\.)*\d+$)/
```

Find zero, one or more of digit and dot groupings followed by one or more digits.

Thanks rsplak for the fiddle; our regexes both appear to solve this issue. [Mine in action](http://jsfiddle.net/4qwnn/2/).